# How to query JSON to deplane JSON containg more than one array values in Stream analytics

Tags: json, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

I want to query below JSON input data received from IotHub in stream analytics

```
{
            "DeviceId": "12355",
            "Message": {
                        "TimeStamp": [{"Time": "1"}, {"Time": "2"}],
                        "Streak": "4",
                        "Checkin": [{"Time": "3"}, {"Time": "4"}],
                        "Status": ""
            }
}
```

I have used below query which is giving me four outputs after applying cross I just want two outputs

I want my output to be in below format.

```
DeviceID    Streak  TimeStamp   Checkin  Status
  "12355"   "4"     "1"         "3"      ""
  "12355"   "4"     "2"         "4"      ""
```

This is the query I wrote using Cross Apply

```
SELECT
 [Stat].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId],

 [Stat].[Message].[Streak] AS [Streak],
 [Stat].[Message].[Status] AS [Status],
 [Stat].[Message].[Error] AS [Error],
 [Stat].[UseTime].[Time] AS [Checkin],
 [Stat].[Open].[Time] AS [OpenTime]
 INTO
 Messages
FROM
(
 SELECT
 [EventAlias].*,
 [Checkin].[ArrayValue] AS [UseTime],
[OutputTime].[ArrayValue] AS [Open]
 FROM [SmartCapData] AS [EventAlias]
 CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(EventAlias.Message.Checkin) AS [Checkin]
 CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(EventAlias.Message.Timestamp) AS [OutputTime]
) AS Stat
```

In the above it is applying cross over cross I want to use it in parallel,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure 'deplane' is the right word here? If you can transform the JSON first you could rewrite it so that timestamp and checkin are both properties of a single structure and store an array of those instead of separate arrays. I guess what you want to do is to join the two arrays on index if that's possible, but I've not seen SQL querying JSON like this before to know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    inputevents.DeviceId,
    inputevents.Message.Streak, 
    inputevents.Message.Status, 
    a.ArrayValue.Time AS Timestamp, 
    GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(inputevents.Message.Checkin, a.ArrayIndex), 'Time') AS Checkin
FROM inputevents
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(inputevents.Message.TimeStamp) a
```

Alternative way to do complex JSON transformations is to use custom JavaScript function.